# How to access actual rendered HTML created by dangerouslySetInnerHTML in Enzyme tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

My component renders HTML using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property. I need to access this rendered HTML in my *enzyme* tests. How can I do that?

I already tried `component.html()` but it returns something like `<button ...>[object Object]</button>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access it via the component props ...

```
const { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html } } = component.props();

console.log('__html', __html);
```